# dynamodb how do i mock mapper?

Tags: java, mockito, amazon-dynamodb

I have a section of dynamoDb related code that I want to test using mockito.

The method I want to test contains the following line:

```
List<NotificationFeedRecord> listResult = mapper.query(NotificationFeedRecord.class, queryExpression);
```

It's work fine when I test by hand, I submit a query and get the expected results back from dynamodb.

I'm writing unit tests and want to mock mapper.query.

I have:

```
mapper = mock(DynamoDBMapper.class);
List<NotificationFeedRecord> testList = new ArrayList<>();
when(mapper.query(any(), any())).thenReturn(testList);
```

Here I get an error

```
Error:(133, 37) java: no suitable method found for thenReturn(java.util.List<notificationfeed.lib.db.NotificationFeedRecord>)
      (argument mismatch; java.util.List<notificationfeed.lib.db.NotificationFeedRecord> cannot be converted to com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.PaginatedQueryList<java.lang.Object>)
```

I've tried a range of fixes (e.g. Creating PaginatedQueryList and returning that, changing the query matchers), but all given an error.

The .query method is declared as follows:

```
public <T> PaginatedQueryList<T> query(Class<T> clazz, DynamoDBQueryExpression<T> queryExpression) {
        return query(clazz, queryExpression, config);
    }
```

How does one mock mapper.query?  Is there something special about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was simple really, I had to mock the PaginatedQueryList and then:

```
when(mapper.query(any(), anyObject())).thenReturn(paginatedQueryList)
```

;

That worked for me.

These are all the conditions I set-up for our tests:

```
@Mock private PaginatedQueryList paginatedQueryList;
doReturn(mockQuery).when(utilSpy).getQueryExpression();

when(mockQuery.withFilterExpression(anyString())).thenReturn(mockQuery);
when(mockQuery.withLimit(anyInt())).thenReturn(mockQuery);
when(mockQuery.withExpressionAttributeValues(anyMap())).thenReturn(mockQuery);
when(mockQuery.withIndexName(anyString())).thenReturn(mockQuery);
when(mockQuery.withHashKeyValues(anyString())).thenReturn(mockQuery);
when(mockQuery.withConsistentRead(anyBoolean())).thenReturn(mockQuery); 
when(mockQuery.withRangeKeyCondition(anyString(), anyObject())).thenReturn(mockQuery);
when(mapper.query(any(), anyObject())).thenReturn(paginatedQueryList);
```

Comment: Can you post a example for mocking  PaginatedQueryList?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i've added the conditions that we setup, however the test itself is really specific to our code and in this case large.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I've a a list which add results of the query, i.e., list.addAll(paginatedQueryList); When I use a mock object this fails with a NPE. Any suggestions how to solve it?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply.  Not without seeing the code.  If it's still an issue can you raise a separate question and message me with a link?  I'll take a look

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just missing the correct matchers for the when() method. You can do something like this:

```
when(mapper.query(Matchers.anyListOf(NotificationFeedRecord.class), anyString()).thenReturn(testList);
```

Documentation for the anyListOf() matcher is [here](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Matchers.html#anyListOf(java.lang.Class))

Comment: I've tried lots of variations of matchers but it doesn't help. With anyListOf I get a cannot resolve method error for the mock (specifically on this part of the mock). The definition for .query method is normal (I've added it to the question).